# customtkinter is not recognised by VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tkinter, customtkinter

I am in my early steps to learning python GUI.
I am using customtkinter library.
I have installed the customtkinter on my system.
I created a virtual environment within my project folder
with:

`python -m venv 'myvenv'`

and activated the env with:

`source <path to activate file within 'myvenv' >`

suprisingly the customtkinter module still isn't recognized when I import it to my file,
despite being installed (I did pip list on both local and virtual env).

I'm using macOS 12 and python 3.10.6.

help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was caused by the incorrect Python interpreter.

You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps resolved the issue for me:

1. Download the customtkinter module from its **github repo** ->
   [customtkinter github repo](https://github.com/tomschimansky/customtkinter)
   You will find the `Download ZIP` option on clicking the green `Code` button
2. Unzip the file and **copy the folder** named `customtkinter`
3. **Paste** the folder into your **project folder**
4. Open vscode in that folder and import customtkinter as usual.

vscode should recognise it now.